# Array diff with multilevel array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this this multilevel array :

`$productpacks` . Example `$productpacks[0][0]` is 4355 .

Now, I have another array that is simple : `$codescart[]` . Example `$codescart[0]` is 4355 .

I am trying to differ those two like this (it does not seem to work) :

```
foreach($productpacks as $pack) {
    $diff = array_diff($pack, $codescart);
    if (empty($diff)) {
        // $cart contains this pack
    }
}
```

Does that work for anybody ? or were is the problem if any ...

Comment: Please post example data as an initialization script if you want us to test. Just knowing that $productpacks[0][0] is 4355 is not enough... tx

Comment: This should work. Please post a complete example as Mathieu said.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)?

```
foreach($productpacks as $pack) {
  if (in_array($pack, $codescart)) {
    // $cart contains this pack
  }
}
```